# Getting code H81 on heroku app deployment

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I have all the files like app.json,Procfile,package.json,server.js in my app folder. Initialized Git,added the changes,made a commit. Then created the heroku, got the online Heroku URL.

But now on hitting the url it says "H81" implying there is no single code in the app that you have created. But I have all the changes pushed, Why is it saying so?

Help me. cheers!

logs :

```
2018-01-17T01:57:41.271777+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=benzos-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=54def654-315e-496c-8d26-7a1a30c05dad fwd="14.139.155.24" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Did you `git push heroku master`? You mention adding and committing, but not pushing.

Comment: Ohh man! Thanks a ton. So stupid of me. Thanks once again

Comment: Glad it worked! I'll turn my comment into an answer, to help future readers who run into the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding and committing your changes, you must push them to Heroku. The default command for this, assuming you followed [Heroku's instructions for creating a git remote](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote), is:

`git push heroku master`